# IPhone TableView Header Behavior Customization

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header, position, docking

Anyone know of a way to customize the TableView header docking behavior, or a framework that does this?

Specifically, if you pop open the iPod app, you will notice that in your list of artists, the letter-header docks at the top.  Then, when you scroll down further, the next header "pushes" the first one up.

This little mechanic can be used quite creatively: for example, let us say that you have a tableview full of content.  The content has two "modes" so you need a segmented control at the top of the tableview, which will toggle the behavior of the content in the cells.  Then, you also want something decorative in the top of your screen--like a logo.

One interesting approach to this would be to make the logo a header, and the segmented control in a different header.  The logoHeader would be the header for section 0, and the segmentedHeader would be the header for section 1.  Section 0 would have no cells (or if UITableView squawks at this, you could add a 0px or a 1px row) while Section 1 would contain all of your content.  So, a bit like this:

---

LOGO HEADER

---

SegControlHeader

---

Content

---

Content

---

Content

---

Content

---

Content

---

(SO's formatting functionality prevents my ASCII art from looking quite how I intended, but that's fine.)

So, what does this do?  Well, the whole screen responds to scrolling since it's all one table view.  But while the logoHeader will go up offscreen, the segControlHeader will dock at the top, and the rest of the content will pass up behind it.  It's just an interesting docking effect, and with good design and artwork you can create neat effects.

Now, the problem comes when your designers want to take it up to the next level.  "This should dock here and this should dock here, and this thing will start partially concealed beyond the bounds of the tableview when you open the view (like a search bar)" etc.  Additional headers within the content need to be there and to dock, and so on.

Anyway, there's a whole range of complexity that you can get into with these kind of docking effects, and almost instantly the tableview becomes insufficient.  Does anyone know a good way to do this, or a framework of some kind that can accomplish this same behavior?

Perhaps the easiest way would be to use a scrollview, read the contentOffset and then reposition things within the content view accordingly, MIN-ed or MAX-ed to specific ranges within the scroll view?